# Start a program with a specified application

Tags: c#, command-line

I'm trying to open a zip file with an Emulator, and I'm having a bit of difficulty. Everything I'm reading says to use Process.Start, but that is not working. Here is the code I use:

```
Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + "\\Emulators\\Genesis\\Fusion.exe", 
              Application.StartupPath + "\\Emulators\\Genesis\\Roms\\Aladdin.zip");
```

The Emulator opens up, but the game isn't loaded into it. The strange part is if I type that into a command prompt it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Change `Application.StartupPath + "Emulators\\Genesis\\Roms\\Aladdin.zip"` to `Application.StartupPath + "\\Emulators\\Genesis\\Roms\\Aladdin.zip"`. You're missing \\ before "Emulators".